# .Net Core XML remove wrapping tags for a list

Tags: xml, wcf, .net-core, messagecontract

I am currently trying to format an XML response to match a specific format and I am having issues with displaying tags I would prefer to hide.

So my current response is as follows:

```
            <ExportShipmentsResult>
                <dataExtract>
                    <DataExtract>
                        <shipment>
                            <ShipID>123456</ShipID>
                            <ShipNo>PSS111198</ShipNo>
                            <ShipDate>5 Dec 2011 14:44</ShipDate>
                            <CustCode>1111/1</CustCode>
                            <ShipSumm>SU</ShipSumm>
                            <PONumbers>por:0121</PONumbers>
                            <ShipComments />
                            <SuperUsers />
                            <OrderItem>
                                <orderItem>
                                    <Code>100001</Code>
                                    <Qty>1</Qty>
                                </orderItem>
                                <orderItem>
                                    <Code>100002</Code>
                                    <Qty>1</Qty>
                                </orderItem>
                            </OrderItem>
                        </shipment>
                    </DataExtract>
                </dataExtract>
            </ExportShipmentsResult>
        </ExportShipmentsResponse>
```

My Issue is I do not want the "Wrapping" tags to display, so taking OrderItem as and example, the result I would like is:

```
                            <SuperUsers />
                                <OrderItem>
                                    <Code>100001</Code>
                                    <Qty>1</Qty>
                                </OrderItem>
                                <OrderItem>
                                    <Code>100002</Code>
                                    <Qty>1</Qty>
                                </OrderItem>
                        </shipment>
```

I have OrderItem set up as a list and I am using the MessageContract(IsWrapped=false) but it doesnt appear to be working, no errors it is just ignored.

Model:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.magishop.com/")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.magishop.com/", IsNullable = false)]
    [MessageContract]
    public partial class ExportShipmentsResponse
    {

        private string resultField;

        [MessageBodyMember]/// <remarks/>
        public List<dataExtract> ExportShipmentsResult { get; set; }
    }

    public class dataExtract
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public List<shipment> DataExtract { get; set; }

    }

    public class shipment
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string ShipID { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string ShipNo { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string ShipDate { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string CustCode { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string ShipSumm { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string PONumbers { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string ShipComments { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string SuperUsers { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public List<orderItem> OrderItem { get; set; }
    }
    [MessageContract(IsWrapped=false)]
    public class orderItem
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string Qty { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is where I build the list of orderItems and add it to my shipments.

```
public class CallbackService : ICallbackService
    {
        public Task<ExportShipmentsResponse> ExportShipments(ExportShipments request)
        {
            orderItem orderitem1 = new orderItem()
            {
                Code = "100001",
                Qty = "1"
            };

            orderItem orderitem2 = new orderItem()
            {
                Code = "100002",
                Qty = "1"
            };

            List<orderItem> orderItems = new List<orderItem>();

            orderItems.Add(orderitem1);
            orderItems.Add(orderitem2);

            shipment shipment = new shipment()
            {
                ShipID = "123456",
                ShipNo = "PSS111198",
                ShipDate = "5 Dec 2011 14:44",
                CustCode = "1111/1",
                ShipSumm = "SU",
                PONumbers = "por:0121",
                ShipComments = "",
                SuperUsers = "",
                OrderItem = orderItems
            };

            List<shipment> shipments = new List<shipment>();

            shipments.Add(shipment);

            dataExtract dataExtract = new dataExtract()
            {
                DataExtract = shipments
            };

            List<dataExtract> dataExtracts = new List<dataExtract>();

            dataExtracts.Add(dataExtract);

            return Task.FromResult(new ExportShipmentsResponse
            {
                ExportShipmentsResult = dataExtracts
            });
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on what I may be missing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not how web services, SOAP and WCF work. You don't "format an XML response".  The SOAP operations are already defined in a WSDL document and the DTOs in XSDs. You don't format the XML, you generate classes from the WSDL document and use them. There are no "wrapping" tags. You can't have raw collection items in a parent element

Comment: Why don't you use .NET's tools to generate the DTOs from the XSD? Why write them by hand? The WSDL document and XSDs aren't optional. Without them, you don't have a SOAP web service. Having them means you can generate clients and servers automatically, using tools.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your comments above, my apologies that me terminology was not correct I am still learning with this stuff. Your second suggestion helped me solve my problem. We had not been given access to XSD's but I used the expected response example the client had provided to generate one and that helped overcome my issue's. If you want to add your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether it is a client-side or a server-side.But you can check out the IClientMessageInspector for client-side and the IDispatchMessageInspector for server-side.The interface contains add and remove methods for reference.

The link below may solve the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector?view=netframework-4.8.

Thanks.